# how to insert a loop in a String toString() method in java

Tags: java

I am looking to pass a long list of results in a String toString() method,this is my code

```
public void newlist(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= nbComposant;i++){
        System.out.print(ref+i+" (quantity  "+quantity+i+")");
    }
}

public String toString(){
    return newlist();
}
```

What's wrong with it?

Comment: the return type of your newlist() method is `void`. Should be String.

Comment: Why is `newList` separate method? Also why does it not return anything (its return type is `void`)?

Comment: Are `ref` and `quantity` arrays?  Do you intend to print each element of these arrays on separate lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public String newlist(){
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for(int i = 0 ; i <= nbComposant;i++){
        sb.append(ref+i+" (quantity  "+quantity+i+")");
    }
   return sb.toString();
}
public String toString(){
    return newlist();
}
```

Comment: what about a line break?

Comment: Do you try to iterate an array with `+quantity+i+`.

Comment: I doubt whether this actually does exactly what NadNet wants.  What would be the point of repeating `ref` and `quantity`?  Most likely, these are actually arrays which NadNet wants to iterate through.

Comment: his question was how to get a value from his list in the .toString().  i'm not a mind reader.

Comment: Yes, you're not a mind reader.  And that's why Stack Overflow makes it possible to comment on questions - so that we can seek clarification when the question is unclear, before jumping in and answering it.  The question _does_ say "I am looking to pass a long list of results" - which should be enough of a hint that this approach is not going to do what the OP needs.

Answer (score 3):

```
public String toString(){
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(256); 
        for(int i = 0 ; i <= nbComposant;i++){
            builder.append(ref).append(i).append(" (quantity  ").append((quantity+i)).append(")");
        }
        return builder.toString();
}
```

You dont need Separate method for this. Use Stringbuilder instead of "+" . Though Recent JVM converts into Stringbuilder it would be good practice to write it.

I dont know what is your excepted Result String. I just copied from your question.